# How can you update a table using the lag function on a loop?

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql

I've already spent hours trying to figure this out but I can't, so I turn to the experts now.
This is how my table looks like:

```
RowNumber    SeriesNumber
1                  1
2                  0
3                  0
4                  0
1                  2
2                  0
1                  3
2                  0
1                  4
```

This is how I want it to look like:

```
RowNumber    SeriesNumber
1                  1
2                  1
3                  1
4                  1
1                  2
2                  2
1                  3
2                  3
1                  4
```

I basically want all the zeros (one by one, so I guess on a loop?) to take the value of the row directly above them. Is it really that difficult or I am just not smart enough?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a column to *order* the records, like an identity column or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `rowNumberTotal` column as an overall ordering, then this is pretty easy.  Here is a mechanism using window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(seriesnumber) over (partition by prev_rownumbertotal) as imputed_seriesnumber
      from (select t.*,
                   max(case when seriesnumber > 0 then rownumbertotal end) over (order by rownumbertotal) as prev_rownumbertotal
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set seriesnumber = imputed_seriesnumber
    where seriesnumber = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to be solvable, you do need a column that can be used to *order* the records, like an identity column. I assume that such a column exists and is called `id`.

You can use an updatable CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select t.*, lag(SeriesNumber) over(order by id) lagSeriesNumber
    from mytable t
)
update cte set SeriesNumber = lagSeriesNumber where SeriesNumber = 0
```

Comment: That almost worked! It updated the first zero after every seriesnumber. How can I incorporate a while loop so it also updates the rest of the zeroes? The table I shared is just an example, the real one has millions of rows

Comment: For anyone interested, the code that worked was using the one suggested plus adding a loop, so in the end it looked like this:                                                   while 1=1
begin
with cte as (
    select *, lag(SeriesNumber) over(order by RowNumberTotal) lagSeriesNumber
    from Table1
)
update cte set SeriesNumber = lagSeriesNumber where SeriesNumber = 0
if @@RowCount = 0
break
end

Comment: I can't see any reason for a loop here @Incompetent77 . A Loop is an awfully slow way to do anything in an RDBMS. Possibly the *slowest* way.